# How can i access web api which is hosted in localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost

I have problem with hostname.

At starting  using url i can access web api methods.

```
http://localhost:49809/QuickBook/Import/QB
```

But i have added host name in host file.like :

```
127.0.0.1       xxx
```

I can now access using this : `http://XXX/QuickBook/Import/QB`

i went back again and tried to access using localhost. now it is not finding..i am getting error : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Note : i have removed host name in host file.

can any one explain why it is not accessing through locahost once it is changed in host file.

And how can i resolve this..

Answer (score 1):

The default IP for `localhost` is `127.0.0.1` which you mapped to `xxx`. You can modify the host file like this, and they will both work:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  xxx
```

Comment: thanks for your help. i am able to connect using loclhost in fiddler. my url is :http://localhost/QuickBook/Import/QB. let me  is not possible connect with port number like : http://localhost:49809/QuickBook/Import/QB.(web api project is running)

Comment: sorry for that, i am able to connect through the port number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
IIS -> Create Site

Binding -> yoursitename.anyextension

Project -> properties -> Web -> Use Local IIS server -> ProjectUrl: http://yoursitename.anyextension
```